# My window manager crashed; now TeXiFy-IDEA thinks I'm missing biblatex, fontenc, and inputenc, and have a bunch of undefined references

Tags: texify-idea

I'm using the TeXiFy-IDEA plugin in PyCharm, on Elementary OS. I managed to do something in Google Chrome that froze my window manager. I logged in to a terminal and killed the chrome group. When I switched back to my GUI, the window manager had crashed and I was returned to the login screen.

When I restarted PyCharm, TeXiFy was reporting that I was missing support for `\autocite`, missing support for a bibliograpy, and I had a whole bunch of figure references that were now undefined.

When I tried to use the `Quick Fix` option, the "missing" packages got added to the top of the file I was looking at instead of my main `.tex` file, which already had the packages there.

How can I fix this?

(Also, I tried tagging this with `pycharm` and `texify-idea` but those tags don't exist,  I don't have enough reputation to add them, and `texify` is about `MikTeX`, not `TeXiFy-IDEA`.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a menu option under the `File` menu called `Repair IDE...`. When you select it, there are several steps the IDE will try to repair things. One step will re-read indexes, one step will reload the project; they are successive, and after each you can click the button that says "everything works now" or "next" (or whatever the labels are). It took the first three steps for everything to start working again.